# Getting String values from Oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I had a table in Oracle database that contains id, name fields.

It's data is:

123,'South'

121,'East'

445,'Africa & World'

When I select rows using where clause like

select * from  where name = 'Africa & World';

Oracle Asks for a Substitution Variable and no records are returned.

Kindly tell me to further clarify my question.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `&` is reserved as a marker for binding variables. You need to escape the `&` symbol.

You can escape the ampersand by

```
SET ESCAPE ON;
select * from where name = 'Africa \& World';
```

or you can set the bindings off by

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
select * from where name = 'Africa & World';
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_FAQ

Option #1

```
SET DEFINE ~
SELECT 'Laurel & Hardy' FROM dual;
```

Option #2

```
SET ESCAPE '\'
SELECT '\&abc' FROM dual;
```

Options #3

```
SET SCAN OFF
SELECT '&ABC' x FROM dual;
```

Option #4

```
SELECT 'Laurel ' || '&' || ' Hardy' FROM dual;
```

Option #5 (Use the 10g Quoting mechanism)

```
SELECT q'{This is Orafaq's 'quoted' text field}' FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: My preference has always been option #3 `SET SCAN OFF`

Answer (score 0):

This is a SQL*Plus thing.

At the SQL*Plus prompt, type:

```
SET DEFINE OFF
```

Then try re-running your statement.